# Get entity name from class object

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following code:

```
namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class User {
...
}

$user = new User();
```

Does anybody know how I can now get the entity name (`AcmeStoreBundle:User`) from the `User` object?

Comment: What is  "the entity name" in your example?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This should always work (no return of Proxy class):

```
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager(); 
$className = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($object))->getName();
```

**As `getClassMetadata` is deprecated, you can now use `getMetadataFor`**

```
$entityName = $this->em->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataFor(get_class($object))->getName();
```

Comment: Does the job. Any advantages compared to Wojciech's approach?

Comment: As @chopchop pointed out, proxies like `Proxies\__CG__\MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity` are correctly handled. This is especially important if you fetch entites from a database.

Comment: @benske If I do a dump on the entity, I see a __CLASS__ property. Is that the same property that get_class() unreliably references? Or is that a reliable a value? For simplicity sake I would ideally like to reference this from a dynamic trait that is added to a versionable entity, where we don't have access to container.

Comment: In Doctrine 2.4.8 this method returns the fully qualified class name. How do you get the short name, e.g. `AcmeStoreBundle:User`??

Answer (score 9):

getClassMetadata() is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use getMetadataFor() instead:

```
$entityName = $this->em->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataFor(get_class($entity))->getName();
```

Or a complete function:

```
/**
 * Returns Doctrine entity name
 *
 * @param mixed $entity
 *
 * @return string
 * @throws \Exception
 */
private function getEntityName($entity)
{
    try {
        $entityName = $this->em->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataFor(get_class($entity))->getName();
    } catch (MappingException $e) {
        throw new \Exception('Given object ' . get_class($entity) . ' is not a Doctrine Entity. ');
    }

    return $entityName;
}
```

Comment: Sorry to jump in on this question but I am facing an issue closest to this. I have a custom entity repository that extends Doctrine's. In my custom repository I have a count function that is suppose to give me a total number of records for whichever entity this method is called on. When I do a print_r I can see what I am looking for but do not knw how to get to it. The "from" method of my QueryBuilder needs to be passed the entity name being queried dynamically. Any help?

Answer (score 8):

PHP [`get_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) function will return `User` and namespace (see comments in php docs).

Comment: Although you are right, this will also return me the entity directory in the namespaced path, so yes i could strip this out but didnt know if there was already a function available in doctrine to get this intended value

Comment: Be carefull using the method sine it won't work everytime. Doctrine use some cache and will generate proxy class. If you use thins method you will have something like this "Proxy\AcmeStoreBundleEntity\Proxy"

Comment: See the other solution, get_class() can fail because it sometimes returns a Proxy class. "$em->getClassMetadata(get_class($object))->getName()" does not. This handles the proxy classes correctly.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Are you sure the "entity name" from Doctrine relates to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use php's **instanceOf** operator:

```
if($a instanceof MyClass) { /*code*/ }
```

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.type.php

Comment: That won't return any "entity name"

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the Class name:

```php
private function getEntityClassName(object $entity): string
{
    return $this->entityManager->getMetadataFactory()>getMetadataFor(
        $entity::class
    )->getReflectionClass()->getShortName();
}
```