# Extract the Namespace or Bundle Shortcut for a Symfony Entity

Tags: php, symfony

I have a function that needs to know the bundle shortcut name for an entity that is passed in.

```
public function doSomething($entity) {
     $bundleShortcut = SOMEFUNCTION($entity);
     // ... do other stuff and return a value ...
}
```

I would love to have it return the bundle shortcut name of my entity:

```
GutensiteCmsBundle:ViewVersion
```

Is this possible? Does the entity manager have access to this metadata somehow?

I'm aware I could pre-register the name in all my entities:

```
class ViewVersion {
    protected $bundleName = 'GutensiteCmsBundle:ViewVersion';
    public function getBundleName() {
        return $this->bundleName;
    }
}
```

Then I can do:

```
$entity->getBundleName();
```

But that's lame.

### SOLUTION

Based on @Chamlee's answer, this is the function I use:

```
public function getEntityBundleShortcut($entity) {
    // wrap in EntityManager's Class Metadata function avoid problems with cached proxy classes
    $path = explode('\Entity\\', $this->em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity))->getName());
    return str_replace('\\', '', $path[0]).':'.$path[1];
}
```

So for the following entities here are the return values:

```
// Entity
Gutensite\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article
// Returns
GutensiteArticleBundle:Article


// Entity
Gutensite\CmsBundle\Entity\View\ViewVersion
// Returns
GutensiteArticleBundle:View\ViewVersion
```

Comment: is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14229984/3854299) right for you?

Comment: @kapa89 that's a great answer. Essentially the same but it wraps `get_class()` with the framework's getClassMetadata function (which is what I was hoping) and avoids problems with cached proxy classes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at this :

```
$className = explode("\\", get_class($document));
```

It returns you an array with all you need ;)
If you make and echo of the $className you'll see the structure and I think it could fit with your problem.

Comment: This is a great answer, but for Symfony, this will apparently cause problems with proxy classes that are cached. So this other solution is recommended: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14229984/3334390